# Unpack string with hexadecimals

Tags: python, struct

I have a string that contains a float value in hexadecimal characters like this:

```
"\\64\\2e\\9b\\38"
```

I want to extract the float, but in order to do that I have to make Python see the string as 4 hex characters, instead of 16 regular characters. First I tried replacing the forward slashes, but I got an error:

```
>>>> hexstring.replace("\\", "\x")
ValueError: invalid \x escape
```

I've discovered

```
struct.unpack("f", "\x64\x2e\x9b\x38")
```

does exactly what I want, but how do I convert the string?

Answer (score 6):

Whenever I see a (malformed) string, such as one composed of this list of characters:

```
['\\', '\\', '6', '4', '\\', '\\', '2', 'e', '\\', '\\', '9', 'b', '\\', '\\', '3', '8']
```

when what was intended was this list of characters

```
['\x64', '\x2e', '\x9b', '\x38']
```

I reach for the `decode('string_escape')` method.

But to use it, we need to replace the two characters `r'\\'` with `r'\x'`.
You can use the `replace(...)` method for that.

```
In [37]: hexstring=r'\\64\\2e\\9b\\38'

In [38]: struct.unpack('f',(hexstring.replace(r'\\',r'\x').decode('string_escape')))
Out[38]: (7.3996168794110417e-05,)

In [39]: struct.unpack("f", "\x64\x2e\x9b\x38")
Out[39]: (7.3996168794110417e-05,)
```

PS. This use of the `decode` method works in Python2 but will not work in Python3. In Python3 `codecs.decode` is meant strictly for converting byte objects to string objects (err, what Python2 calls unicode objects), whereas in the example above, `decode` is actually converting a string object to a string object. Most decoding codecs in Python2 do convert string objects to unicode objects, but a few like `'string_escape'` do not. In general they have been moved to other modules, or called in some other way.

In Python3, the equivalent of `hexstring.decode('string_encode')` is `codecs.escape_decode(hexstring)[0]`.

Edit: Another way, similar in spirit to jsbueno's answer, is to use `binascii.unhexlify`:

```
In [76]: import binascii
In [81]: hexstring=r"\\64\\2e\\9b\\38"
In [82]: hexstring.replace('\\','')
Out[82]: '642e9b38'

In [83]: binascii.unhexlify(hexstring.replace('\\',''))
Out[83]: 'd.\x9b8'
```

These `timeit` results suggest `binascii.unhexlify` is the fastest:

```
In [84]: %timeit binascii.unhexlify(hexstring.replace('\\',''))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.42 us per loop

In [85]: %timeit hexstring.replace('\\','').decode('hex_codec')
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.94 us per loop

In [86]: %timeit hexstring.replace(r'\\',r'\x').decode('string_escape')
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.13 us per loop
```

Edit, per the comments:

> This answer contains raw strings. The
>   Department of Public Health advises
>   that eating raw or undercooked strings
>   poses a health risk to everyone, but
>   especially to the elderly, young
>   children under age 4, pregnant women
>   and other highly susceptible
>   individuals with compromised immune
>   systems. Thorough cooking of raw
>   strings reduces the risk of illness.

Comment: You should emphasise that the trick here involves raw strings.

Comment: @detly: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. Although I use raw strings for convenience of notation, the trick really doesn't depend on the notation. I could rewrite the bits of code without any use of raw strings.

Comment: @detly: Oh... perhaps you mean that the OP said `"\\64\\2e\\9b\\38"` while I started with `r"\\64\\2e\\9b\\38"`. I'm guessing that the OP really meant `r"\\64\\2e\\9b\\38"`, because later in the text he mentions that it is 16 characters long, while `len("\\64\\2e\\9b\\38")` is only 12.

Comment: Yes, nice answer, but I think using the "hex_codec" string codec in this case is much more straightforward (my answer bellow)

Comment: @unutbu - All I meant was that if you're not looking for the `r` prefix, you might not see it :)

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way to go ehre, is to just get rid of the "\" characters, and make python see each two hex-digits as a byte, using the "hex_codec":

```
struct.unpack("f", "\\64\\2e\\9b\\38".replace("\\", "\").decode("hex_codec"))
```